# Getting friend's wall post data via facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have never used facebook API.As part of my research project, I need to get activity data (the posts made, the links shared etc.) of a user's friends. Is it possible to get this data via facebook API? Do i need permission from user only or i need permission from user's friends too for accessing that data? I am assuming that since a user can see wall posts of his friends when he visits his friend's facebook profile, the same thing is possible using the API too.

Comment: You can only access your newsfeed via the Graph API as far as I know. Therefore you need the "read_stream" permission. See docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

Comment: @Tobi i used [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with my account, and i am able to get status updates and other activity of my friends (by using "{friend's id}/statuses" among other things) . So i guess it is possible to get that data via API.

Comment: Good. It's not working for my friends, but this can also be caused by permission settings

Comment: Ah well, what doesn't work is accessing /me/friends/statuses, which means that you probably need to go through your friend list one by one. Or did you find a better solution?

Comment: no, right now the only solution available to me is calling "/{friend's-id}/statuses" via graph api recursively and get the data.